# mod_expires and images from php script

Tags: php, image

I have a php script which returns images with a specific id.

```
getImage.php?id=12
```

I configured some mod_expires preferences. In example.

```
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 minute"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 minute"
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 minute"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 minute"
```

When i look in my chrome developer tools it works on static images but not on the images requested over my php script.

Am i doing anything wrong or what is the problem?

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

You need to set right MIME type and Cache-Control headers inside your getImage.php.

```
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=60');
```

Comment: I do this and it works. Could it be that it doesnt work because the php script is stored on a different server?

Comment: Yes, it will work only when files are requested from server where you configure mod_expires. If your response containing images from remote servers, cache must be configured on this remote servers too.